# Axes formatting with histogram

Tags: r

I am having trouble extending the axes of my histogram to the value that I want: 130 units.
My code:

```
hist(dframe1$Low.calcium.diet, xlim=c(0,130), col="red", nclass=10)
```

My data:

```
High.calcium.diet   Low.calcium.diet
14.5    52.7
18.2    44.4
15  125
14.3    66.4
25.7    23.3
17.3    88.3
23.1    38.8
16.2    42.9
12.7    15.1
18.3    41.6
13.2    53.2
```

I also want the axes to meet at zero.

Comment: But when I try to alter the axes with xlim it does not re center it, and I am not sure how to do that?

Comment: I have! I do not know what 'set.seed' is. I am very new to R.

Comment: Do I use it like this? set.seed(20,40,60,80,100,120) it does not work.

Comment: The bits you need are `hist` and `axis`. I just pointed you to an answer to your question; if you don't know what some function is, the least you can do is google it (`set.seed` and `rnorm` are used to set the data for the example histogram)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first plot your graph without axes, and then add your axes with the parameters you want:

```
hist(dframe1$Low.calcium.diet, xlim=c(0,130), col="red", nclass=10,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
```

xaxt="n" and yaxt="n" tells hist not to plot the x- and y- axes

Then add your axes (1=bottom, and 2=left):

```
axis(1,seq(0,130,10),pos=0)
axis(2,seq(0,3,1),pos=0)
```

Your graph was going to 130, it just wasn't showing the number 130 either because your increment was by 20, or there wasn't enough space because the figure was too small.

And there you go:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much crmhaske for the help. :) It looks alot better. However, when I do it the y axis does not meet the x axis: > hist(dframe1$Low.calcium.diet,axes=FALSE,col="red", main="Histogram of rats fed low calcium diet", nclass=10, xlab="Units of parathyroid hormone per 100ml blood", ylab="Frequency")
> hist(d$Low.calcium.diet, xlim=c(0,130), col="red", nclass=10,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
Error in d$Low.calcium.diet : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> axis(1,seq(0,130,10),pos=0)
> axis(2,seq(0,3,1),pos=0)

Comment: You copied my code exactly, and it created an error. As a result, it never created the plot in the first place. I called my data frame d, and you called yours dframe1. I have edited my code to match yours.

Comment: Nah, my bad. I should have used your convention.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it is very kind of you. :)